# How are Kindle standard pages calculated?

Tags: kindle, amazon

How does Amazon Kindle count a standard page?

Or, if I may ask more specifically:

What is a believable range of character lengths for a standard page as calculated for Amazon Kindle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a plugin for [Calibre](https://calibre-ebook.com/) called [Count Pages](https://www.mobileread.com/forums/showthread.php?t=134000).

It can estimate page and word counts for a given ebook, using various algorithms, and one of them is an APNX estimation based on Amazon Kindle.

You can try to use it and perform your own tests; if you have a decent amount of books, once it has counted the total words of each one and estimated the page numbers, you can do your math and calculate the average words per page.

Answer (score 3):

This can be really hard to estimate without narrowing your question down a bit.

But I just measured a text-heavy book to determine:

**Mobile Phone App** 
852 characters 26 lines

**On a small e-ink device:**

- 1217 characters ...  25 lines (3rd font size from left)
- 802 characters  21 lines  (next larger size font, 2nd from left)

**Large Tablet:**

- 2003 characters 41 lines somewhat small font size
- 1666 characters       37 lines somewhat large font size

Users can adjust text margins and text size, so that plays a role. Also, my sample didn't have many paragraphs or line breaks. I was using a custom font on my large tablet, it seems that Bookerly is slightly smaller, so maybe add an extra 100.